# type casting of strings

Tags: c++, string

I am trying this simple piece of code to accept a string in one function and pass it to other function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void set_name(char *deviceName)
{
    cout<<"Local Device name is:"<<endl;
    cout<<deviceName<<endl;
}

void enter_name()
{
    cout<<"Enter a user friendly name"<<endl;
    string name;
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Entered name is:"<<endl;
    cout << name<<endl;

    set_name(name);
}

int main()
{
    enter_name();

    return 0;
}
```

but when I compile this code I am getting the following errors:

```
 error C2664: 'set_name' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'char *'
```

somebody please help me to sort out this error, make sure I don't want to change the prototype of set_name();

Comment: Use `c_str` like `set_name(name.c_str());`. And read docs before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `set_name` is taking a `char*` parameter, whereas you are attempting to pass a `std::string`. *If* your function parameter was a `const char*`, it would implicitly convert for you:

```
void set_name(const char* name);

std::string name = "MyName";
set_name(name);
```

However, you are telling the compiler that this `char*` is allowed to be modified because it isn't `const`, and a `std::string` and string literal (strings within double-quotes) cannot be modified.

As your function does not change `deviceName`, it makes the most sense to make your parameter a `const char*`; however, it makes even more sense for it to be a `std::string`!

```
void set_name(const std::string& deviceName)
{
    cout<<"Local Device name is:"<<endl;
    cout<<deviceName<<endl;
}
```

Which can be called like:

```
// string literal
set_name("MyDeviceName");
const std::string device = "MyDeviceName";
// string
set_name(device);
// char*
char* device = "MyDeviceName"
set_name(device);
```

BUT, if you **truly** have reasons to pass a `char*` **and don't intend to modify the parameter**, you can call it like so:

```
string name;
...
set_name(&name[0]);
```

Comment: "If you were passing a const char*, it would implicitly convert for you." [Really](http://rextester.com/GAFW42033)?

Comment: Ha whoops my bad, I meant _if the function TOOK a `const char*`_. I clarified meaning

Comment: Thanks Tas this was really helpful